# Is there a Ripple address directory?

Tags: ripple

Not part of the protocol, but rather a 3rd party?

A directory could be built starting from [this thread](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=145506.0), where a lot of known Bitcoin figures posted their Ripple address (myself included).

Comment: The only list I've seen is here: https://github.com/arvicco/rippler/blob/master/lib/rippler/contacts.rb